# What are the best practices for receiving inboud email?

Tags: email, smtp, imap

We are building a ticket system which is supposed to send and receive email. Sending email is relatively easy and can be accomplished in a modular way using SMTP. However we also need to support inbound email. To my understanding there are three main roads we can take.

1. Implementing inbound SMTP, which to my knowledge is quit hard and hard to maintain.
2. Using a SaaS such as (SendGrid, Mailgun, etc) which will deliver incoming email through web hooks. This however increases cost and makes the application dependent on this particular service (we are open source).
3. Using IMAP. This seems to be the most modular approach to me, but IMAP is a more user centric protocol. I also can not find any good experience about using this for incoming mail.

What are your experiences and what do you suggest?

Comment: Implementing inbound SMTP is dead easy and very robust. Try that first.

Comment: Using a hook with inbound SMTP is the most straightforward.  You can just have it run a script on every message received.  If you implement IMAP you have to worry about a whole new class of robustness problems.